# When sidebar open the body will push left

Tags: jquery, html, css, toggle

I am trying to build an effect so that when I click on a button, a sidebar will open and push body of page to left. My button is working but body does not push to left.Here is my full code. I try give more class for body but not working.

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#sidebar-btn').click(function(){
    $('#sidebar').toggleClass('visible');
    $('.body-menu').toggleClass('.body-menu-left');
   });
  })
```

```css
body{
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
 font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial;
}

#sidebar{
 background:black;
 width: 370px;
 height:100%;
 display: block;
 position: fixed;
 left:-370px;
 top:0px;
 transition: left 0.3s linear;
}
#sidebar.visible{
 left:0px;
 transition: left 0.3s linear;
}
ul{
 margin:0px;
 padding: 0px;
 padding-top: 65px;
}
ul li{
 list-style: none;
 padding-top: 10px;
}
ul li a{
 background:black;
 border-bottom:1px solid #111;
 display: block;
 width: 280px;
 padding: 10px;
 text-decoration: none;
}
#font1{
  color:gray;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none
}
#font2{
 color:white;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-decoration: none
}
#sidebar-btn{
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 width:20px;
 height: 15px;
 cursor: pointer;
 margin:20px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 right:-60px;
}
#sidebar-btn span{
 height:1px;
 background:white;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 display: block;
}
#sidebar-btn span:nth-child(2){
 width:75%;
}
#sidebar-btn span:nth-child(3){
 width:50%;
}
#title-menu{
 color: white;
 letter-spacing: 15px; 
 padding-left: 25px;
}
#title-menu > h2{
 padding-left: 20px;
}
/*hover*/
.hvr-underline-from-left {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;

}
.hvr-underline-from-left:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: white !important; 
  height: 2px !important;
  -webkit-transition-property: right;
  transition-property: right;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.hvr-underline-from-left:hover:before, .hvr-underline-from-left:focus:before, .hvr-underline-from-left:active:before {
  right:60;
  background-color: white;
}

/*Fliphvr*/
/* Set-up */


/* Container box to set the sides relative to */
.cube {
 width: 30%;
 padding-left: 20px;
 height: 50px;
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .10s;
 transition: transform .10s; /* Animate the transform properties */
 -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 transform-style: preserve-3d; /* <-NB */
}

/* The two faces of the cube */
.flippety,.flop {
 background: black; 
 height: 50px;
}

/* Position the faces */
.flippety {
 -webkit-transform: translateZ(50px);
 transform: translateZ(50px);
}

.flop {
 -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(-50px);
 transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(-50px);
}

/* Rotate the cube */
.cube:hover {
 -webkit-transform: rotateX(89deg);
 transform: rotateX(89deg); /* Text bleed at 90º */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <title>Sidebar</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/hover.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/hover-min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
</head>
<body background="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/3bvnoqsvY-M/maxresdefault.jpg">
 <div>
 <div id="sidebar">
  <div id="title-menu"><h2>CRIMINAL</h2></div>
  <ul>
   <li><div class="cube">
   <div class="flippety">
   <a href="#" id="font1">HOME</a>
   </div>
   <div class="flop">
   <a href="#" class="hvr-underline-from-left" id="font2">HOME</a>
   </div>
   </div>
   </li>
   <li><div class="cube">
   <div class="flippety">
   <a href="#" id="font1">THE STORY</a>
   </div>
   <div class="flop">
   <a href="#" class="hvr-underline-from-left" id="font2">THE STORY</a>
   </div>
   </div>
   </li><li><div class="cube">
   <div class="flippety">
   <a href="#" id="font1">CAST & FILM MAKERS</a>
   </div>
   <div class="flop">
   <a href="#" class="hvr-underline-from-left" id="font2">CAST & FILM MAKERS</a>
   </div>
   </div>
   </li><li><div class="cube">
   <div class="flippety">
   <a href="#" id="font1">GALLERY</a>
   </div>
   <div class="flop">
   <a href="#" class="hvr-underline-from-left" id="font2">GALLERY</a>
   </div>
   </div>
   </li><li><div class="cube">
   <div class="flippety">
   <a href="#" id="font1">VIDEOS</a>
   </div>
   <div class="flop">
   <a href="#" class="hvr-underline-from-left" id="font2">VIDEOS</a>
   </div>
   </div>
   </li><li><div class="cube">
   <div class="flippety">
   <a href="#" id="font1">ARE YOU A PSYCHOPATH?</a>
   </div>
   <div class="flop">
   <a href="#" class="hvr-underline-from-left" id="font2">ARE YOU A PSYCHOPATH?</a>
   </div>
   </div>
   </li>
  </ul>
 <div id="sidebar-btn">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
 </div>
 </div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you add your CSS code please ?

Comment: What side is your sidebar on? Do you mean push to the right?

Comment: i add full code now :( anyone can help ?

Comment: @duykhanh you have no class called body-menu-left defined, so how can you toggle it? that would help!

Comment: i add more class : body-menu-left{
left:370px;
}
but i still have error :(

Comment: @duykhanh please note that i don't get messages unless you tag me in them like '@RachelGallen' at the start. I only saw this now. What are you trying to do exactly? your code looks fine? Do you want to shift the background over? Or narrow the nav bar?

Comment: @RachelGallen sorry my English not good. i add class body-menu-left like you said and have a properties left:370px, then i toogle but still not work . i mean the page dosen't push to right . i don't know what i wrong .

Comment: @duykhanh but I don't know what you mean, do you want background to push right or just page content? (Use Google translate!!)

Comment: @RachelGallen i want both page content and back-ground push right :D

Comment: @duykhanh Page content no problem, background is a bit tricky.

Comment: @RachelGallen background i will do it soon but i need page content push to right first . do you have something to read or some example ? thanks you :D

Comment: @duykhanh sorted the background https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/f519gbwm/

Comment: @RachelGallen thanks you , now i know how it work. thanks you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you're looking for, but in the below snippet, if you click where it says 'Menu' the sidebar will shift to the left. The links will obviously lead to wherever you indicate

I have a fiddle (from a while ago) at https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/sokq4956/1/

```js
$("#menu-toggle").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("active");
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
    padding-left: 70px;
    transition: all .4s ease 0s;
    height: 100%
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
    margin-left: -150px;
    left: 70px;
    width: 150px;
    background: #222;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 10000;
    transition: all .4s ease 0s;
}

.sidebar-nav {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#page-content-wrapper {
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
#wrapper.active {
    padding-left: 150px;
}
#wrapper.active #sidebar-wrapper {
    left: 150px;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

#sidebar_menu li a, .sidebar-nav li a {
    color: #999;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 150px;
    background: #252525;
    border-top: 1px solid #373737;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #1A1A1A;
    -webkit-transition: background .5s;
    -moz-transition: background .5s;
    -o-transition: background .5s;
    -ms-transition: background .5s;
    transition: background .5s;
}
.sidebar_name {
    padding-top: 25px;
    color: #fff;
    opacity: .7;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
  line-height: 40px;
  text-indent: 20px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
  color: #999999;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
  height: 65px;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
  color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: none;
}

.content-header {
  height: 65px;
  line-height: 65px;
}

.content-header h1 {
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 20px;
  line-height: 65px;
  display: inline-block;
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
    #wrapper {
    padding-left: 70px;
    transition: all .4s ease 0s;
}
#sidebar-wrapper {
    left: 70px;
}
#wrapper.active {
    padding-left: 150px;
}
#wrapper.active #sidebar-wrapper {
    left: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    transition: all .4s ease 0s;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper" class="active">
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
      <ul id="sidebar_menu" class="sidebar-nav">
           <li class="sidebar-brand"><a id="menu-toggle" href="#">Menu </a></li>
      </ul>
        <ul class="sidebar-nav" id="sidebar">     
          <li><a href="/index.html">Link1</a></li>
          <li><a>link2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
        <!-- Page content -->
        <div id="page-content-wrapper">
            <!-- Keep all page content within the page-content inset div! -->
            <div class="page-content inset">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <p class="well lead">Click on the Menu to Toggle Sidebar </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Hope this helps

Rachel

Comment: @duykhanh I made a new fiddle for you with content show/hide in it https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/u3td4wwx/2/